# How can I get all the documents which have at least the properties specified in an Elasticsearch query?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

It is possible to select an item from the index which match multiple values for a certain sub-item? I think this is not so clear but I added more details below.

I have the following index:

`{
    "mappings" : {
        "entity" : {
            "properties" : {
                "name" : {"type" : "string"},
                "features" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "include_in_parent" : false,
                    "properties" : {
                        "id" : {"type" : "integer"},
                        "value_int" : {"type" : "integer"},
                        "value_text" : {"type" : "string"},
                        "value_decimal" : {"type" : "integer"}

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}`

Some items from the index

```
{
"name" : "Bazar",
"features" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "value_text" : null,
        "value_decimal" : null,
        "value_int": 51
    },        
    {
        "id" : 9,
        "value_text" : "Amsterdam",
        "value_decimal" : null,
        "value_int": null
    }      
]
```

}

```
{
"name" : "Bazar Test",
"features" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "value_text" : null,
        "value_decimal" : null,
        "value_int": 52
    },        
    {
        "id" : 9,
        "value_text" : "Leiden",
        "value_decimal" : null,
        "value_int": null
    }      
]
```

}

```
{
"name" : "Bazar no city",
"features" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "value_text" : null,
        "value_decimal" : null,
        "value_int": 51
    },        
]
```

}

What I need is a way to find just the items which have the features.id = 1 and features.id = 2 (ex: "Bazar" and "Bazar Test" items).

The query I got some far is

```
{
"query" : {
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "features",
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    { "terms" : { "features.id" : [1, 9]} }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem with this query is that it selects the items which have features.id = 1 OR features.id = 9 so all the items are returned.

**Edit**
Tried a new query

```
{
"query" : {
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "features",
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    { "terms" : { 
                            "features.id" : [1, 9], 
                            "minimum_should_match": 2
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But I got no results.

Edit:

After I combined the answers, I managed to get it working.
Thank you for help :)

This is my query (a bit modified)

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 20,
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match_phrase_prefix": {
                            "title": {
                                "query": "deli",
                                "max_expansions": 5
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "entity_type_id": 5
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "and": {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "features",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "features.id": 31
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "features.value_int": {
                                                    "query": [
                                                        56, 57
                                                    ],
                                                    "operator": "and"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: In MySQL, the standard solution looks like this: `SELECT my_column FROM my_table WHERE my_other_column IN('a','b','c') GROUP BY my_column HAVING COUNT([DISTINCT] my_other_column) >= x` -- WHERE x is a number between 1 and n -- where n is the number of arguments supplied within IN()

Comment: Thank you! I was working to get the query in MySQL first and afterwards to adapt it to ES. Now I know the query. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `match` query supports a Boolean `operator` parameter. You should also wrap the query in a `nested` query, as the `features` field is `nested` in your mapping.

Try this query:

```
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "features.id": {
                 "query": "1 9",
                 "operator": "and"
               }
            }
         },
         "path": "features"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested documents are more difficult to query.  This should be what you want:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "features",
                "query": {
                  "term": {
                    "features.id": {
                      "value": "1"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "features",
                "query": {
                  "term": {
                    "features.id": {
                      "value": "9"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```